# Odometer Scroll Speed and Duration Increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll, odometer

I am working on [odometer](https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/) trying increase scroll Duration and speed of every digit of odometer but not working Please Help....

Here is an example:

[Odometer Counter values 0 In Starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56997585/odometer-counter-values-0-in-starting)

Changed Value of Duration in java script file and trying to change other code but not working

I am using code for increase scroll timing but every digit scroll speed not equal first digit is too much slow you can see fowling link

code to Increase Duration and digits are slow

```
**Every Digit scroll Speed mast be fast or equal **
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamschwartz/89xrn9bv/)

All code are Available below following Link

[Odometer Counter values 0 In Starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56997585/odometer-counter-values-0-in-starting)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the css transitions if you want to make the animation faster. Here I've adjusted both the javascript and the css to take only 1 second:

Javascript:

```
window.odometerOptions = {
  duration: 1 * 1000
  //,animation: 'count'
};
```

CSS:

```
.odometer.odometer-auto-theme.odometer-animating-up .odometer-ribbon-inner, 
.odometer.odometer-theme-minimal.odometer-animating-up .odometer-ribbon-inner,
.odometer.odometer-auto-theme.odometer-animating-down.odometer-animating .odometer-ribbon-inner, .odometer.odometer-theme-minimal.odometer-animating-down.odometer-animating 
.odometer-ribbon-inner {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s !important;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s !important;
  -ms-transition-duration: 1s !important;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s !important;
  transition-duration: 1s !important
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mfoj6qpw/

Comment: Thanks For Quick Response. Yes animation is faster but what about Scroll Duration?

Comment: need scroll duration long